# Manually throwing status code errors on console

Tags: javascript, reactjs, console

I'm creating a React web application, backed by NodeJS and ExpressJS. My project is not suitable for Server Side Rendering, therefore I'm managing the routing completely using React.

However, while the application successfully redirects to a custom 404 page, it does not output any messages on the console. Since the routing is achieved without SSR, I do not expect that, either. But I could not find a way to properly return a status code error (404 in this case) on the console.

**tldr**: I want to simulate a real 404 error on the console, without actually having the response object.

I've tried `console.error(404)`, but it only outputs this:

[image]

But what I want to see is something like this:

[image]

Any ideas are appreciated.

Comment: Can you send 404 status from your nodejs backend?

Comment: You cannot simulate a 404 error on the console; you have to return a 404 HTTP status code from the server.

Comment: I can do that with ExpressJS, `res.status(404).send("Not Found")`, but that's inside `app.use(function(err,req,res,next){ ... }` function which manages requests and responses. As there is no request-response management on my React code, I cannot natively return the error.

Comment: @chipit24 without static routing using server side rendering, I don't know how I can let the server side know about 404 errors caught on React (with `<Route component={NotFound} />`)

Comment: Why do you need to manually throw a 404 error on the console? If you just want the "404 (Not Found)" error to show up, you could set up a 404 endpoint in Express and send a request to that when you hit an undefined route on the frontend.

Comment: I want to do it, because afaik Google crawlers also interpret those error messages and automatically exclude those pages from indexing. Besides many SEO practices, it helps with error handling for project APIs to detect such error codes. "How" is more important and relevant for what I want to achieve than "why". I'll try that 404 endpoint using some examples i found, but none of them seems to resolve the connection between React and Node. The main problem is, on React it seems to me that there is no undefined route. None of them make server side return a 404.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To be able to achieve receiving `404` GET error codes printed on `console` on a `React` application, some other Server-Side Rendering `(SSR)` implementation (more than just `ExpressJS` custom SSR, but built-in features) is needed. This is automatically done by `NextJS` and I've solved my problem by switching the entire project to be solely written on `NextJS`.

[image: error printed on console]